# A findById operation on the child entity in the 'One to many mapping' scenario returns recursive child entities. Need solution

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 entities with me. JobOfferEntity and JobApplicationEntity. JobOfferEntity has one to many mapping with the JobApplicationEntity. Below are the entities :-

```
public class JobOfferEntity {

@JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "relatedJobOffer",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<JobApplicationEntity> jobApplications = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class JobApplicationEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "app_id")
    private long applicationId;

@JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_OFFER",updatable = false)
    private JobOfferEntity relatedJobOffer;
}
```

I am trying to fetch the job application on the basis of applicationId;

```
JobApplicationEntity jobApplicationEntity = this.jobApplnRepo.findById(appId).orElseThrow(() -> new DataNotFoundException(""));
```

But this operation returns the job application entity , however the problem is it returns the child entity JobOfferEntity and again the job apllication entity embedded inside the Job Offer entity recursively . Please find below json

```
{
    "jobId": 0,
    "applicationId": 1,
    "candidateEmail": "Lalit.mishra@gmail.com",
    "resumeTxt": "Sample resume",
    "applicationStatus": "APPLIED",
    "relatedJobOffer": {
        "jobId": 1,
        "jobTitle": "Amruta  dev",
        "jobDesc": "Sample C++ scientist",
        "contactPerson": "Basho",
        "createdDate": "2019-03-03",
        "modifiedDate": "2019-03-03",
        "jobOfferStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "jobApplications": [
            {
                "applicationId": 1,
                "candidateEmail": "Lalit.mishra@gmail.com",
                "resumeTxt": "Sample resume",
                "applicationStatus": "APPLIED"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As mentioned above I only need the related job offer but I dont want the related job applications in the related job offers again recursively.

Could you please recommend me any solution?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: This is more related to the hibernate fetch operation having an issue as jobApplicationEntity will occupy huge jvm space andnot just serialising objects to json.

Comment: It is likely Jackson that's triggering the fetch of the lazily fetched `JobOfferEntity.jobApplications` property. What you need to do is tell Jackson not to bother trying to access it. It will then not be fetched at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to fetch ( on the clientside) from JobEntity the related JobApplicationEntitys, you can annotate that field with  @JsonIgnore

```
public class JobOfferEntity {

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "relatedJobOffer",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<JobApplicationEntity> jobApplications = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

source: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html

Comment: That will just not include job applications in my json response? But it will still fetch the child objects recursively and occupy jvm memory?

Comment: @Lalit the FetchType that you have on that relationship is LAZY, so it really depends on your application...check https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

Comment: @Lalit you keep using the word 'recursively'. You do understand that when you see the same entity multiple times in the tree, it is the same object reference every time, right?

Comment: Certainly yes, the object reference would be same. Let me detail it out a little more. Please consider the below line in my code :- JobApplicationEntity jobApplicationEntity = this.jobApplnRepo.findById(appId).orElseThrow(() -> new DataNotFoundException("")); I am putting a debugger in this line and checking the tree. I can see the objects recusively in a tree ex : Entity A inside entity B, again when I open entity B, I can see entity A. Do you mean to say that it is fine, just use @JsonIgnore and it will not affect the performance of the fetch or increase the memory foot print?

Comment: @Lalit it sounds like the debugger triggers lazy loading. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985277/trying-to-confirm-lazy-loading-is-working

Comment: Yeah I think that makes sense.